# Is there a Lunar Calendar for Werewolf: The Forsaken?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, werewolf-the-forsaken

So we're finding it a bit difficult to determine what parts of the month are each moon phase.  I don't need something assigned to a real world calendar, just something that tells what each day in the 28 day cycle is what phase of the moon.

I don't need the lunar calendar to correspond to any real date.  All I'm looking for is when the phases change and how long each lasts for the purpose of defining when each werewolf's auspice moon is in the sky.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the benefit of balance when playing Apocalypse games I've worked on the theory that for auspices and such like each of the phases should be roughly the same size. To this end to get the five auspices roughly equal time you need to have five or six days per phase.

The way I've always done that is as follows assuming Day 0 is the new moon:

- Days -2 to 2 (5 days)
- Days 3-5 - waxing crescent (3 days)
- Days 6-8 - waxing Half moon (3 days)
- Days 9-11 - waxing gibbous (3 days)
- Days 12-16 - Full moon (5 days)
- Days 17-19 - Waning gibbous (3 days)
- Days 20-22 - waning half moon (3 days)
- Days 23-25 - waning crescent (3 days)
- Days 26-30 (day 30 is day 2 of the new cycle) - New moon (again) (5 days)

As you can see this gives 5 days for the new and full moon and 6 days total for the intermediate three (in groups of three days waxing and three days waning). Lunar cycles are funny things so these might be a bit fuzzy but this I think is a good rule of thumb.

To the best of my knowledge I don't recall ever having seen this clearly defined in any literature, hence the need to make it up ourselves.

As a final note the reason I've attempted to make each of the phases roughly the same length is because if birth time is random then if half moon was only two days (once each way) then only about 7% (2/28) of werewolves would come under that auspice compared to the crescent which if correspondingly larger might be 10/28 = 35% of werewolves, five times as many proportionally. I've always assumed the auspices are balanced, hence this plan.

Comment: This is much better than my shoddy attempt at writing up a list.  As I was just recently assigned the task of tracking the moon phases I'm rather lost as to how to do so since neither the ST nor the books have detailed exactly when the phases are lol.

Comment: Friends and I spent far too long debating how these things should work. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

**Note: This answer describes the real world phases, and assumes that Werewolf: The Forsaken is intending to correspond with our actual moon**.

[Each moon phase lasts about 7 days (properly, 7.4)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_phase). Therefore, you can assume the moon is new on day 0, waxing for fourteen days (reaching half-moon at day 7), full, then waning for fourteen days (reaching half-moon again at day 21). Full and new moons are usually considered either one day (with the day after beginning the waxing/waning period) or three days (with the day before and after the properly full moon counting as "full enough").

So you'd have either:

- Day 0: New Moon
- Day 1-6: Waxing crescent
- Day 7: Half-moon
- Day 8-13: Waxing gibbous
- Day 14: Full moon
- Day 15-20: Waning gibbous
- Day 21: Half-moon
- Day 22-27: Waning crescent
- Day 28/0: New Moon again

Or, more typical when werewolves are involved:

- Day 27-1: New Moon (begins on day 27 of previous month, then day 28/0, then day 1)
- Day 2-6: Waxing crescent
- Day 7: Half-moon
- Day 8-12: Waxing gibbous
- Day 13-15: Full moon
- Day 16-20: Waning gibbous
- Day 21: Half-moon
- Day 22-26: Waning crescent
- Day 27-1: New Moon again

Comment: it does intend nWoD is our world through a fractured mirror (as they describe it)

Comment: @xenoterracide Yes, but I suppose if they released an official calendar someplace I haven't seen it could contradict one or both of these lists for gameplay balance reasons.

Comment: that's fair enough